# Do questions about SO questions belong on Meta?

Tags: support, meta

I know that Meta mostly covers SO's functionality and regulations, but say I had a question like "what's the most popular question with no answers on SO?" Where would that belong, Meta, or SO?

Comment: Definitely Meta. It may not be well received though

Comment: Yes, it belongs on meta. But be aware that there's a decent chance that it might be closed as "Not Constructive" here anyways.

Comment: [Which is the most popular question on Stackoverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60112)

Comment: @Mysticial This specific example sounds like a question that could be easily answered with a Data Explorer query. I wouldn't call it "not constructive".

Comment: @AnnaLear Yeah, I wouldn't consider it "not constructive" either. But given how meta is, I would bet it would be closed as such anyways. For example, the question Pekka linked to is indeed closed as "not constructive".

Comment: @Mysticial "Not constructive" has to be the most abused close reason. I'm really coming around to, at best, disliking it.

Comment: Hmm perhaps a question on how do you determine the answer would work. As an aside here [Odata query for for it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Posts()?$filter=AnswerCount%20eq%200&$orderby=ViewCount%20desc&$top=1) and here's the [data.se query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/92888/) of course I used viewcount you might want to change it to use score

Comment: @AnnaLear On Meta, NC is certainly the most abused close reason - can we have "noise and pointless" back please? (Not saying that "noise and pointless" would apply here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would belong here on meta. All questions about, concerns with, support for, discussion of, and odes to Stack Overflow are off-topic *on* Stack Overflow, but can be posted here.

That said, normal rules apply: do your research, make sure you provide enough information (define "popular"), be polite and respond to any requests for clarification.